# VMWARE ESXI // Create the datastore with VMFS disk without formating

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmfs, hdd

We've faced the problem.
After the voltage drop, our RAID1 disks in ESXI datastore stopped working.
With the help of the master we've created an exact copy of one of the old disks on the new disk.
It's already formatted as VMFS disk and have all the data and VMs we need.

And here's the issue.
After installing the disk to slot, we see it as the available device with VMFS partition:
[ESXI device screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjnFu.png)

When we try to create the new datastore with the disk, the pop-up with the next text occurs:
***"The entire contents of this disk are about to be erased and replaced with the specified configuration, are you sure?"***

**So, is this possible to create a new datastore without wiping the data from the disk?**
The disk is available via ESXI Shell only as a device, not as a volume.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think what you are getting at here is to mount an existing, not create. This can be done through the esxcli tools, not sure about the UI. Example here https://sahlitech.com/mounting-vmfs-datastore-esxi/

Comment: Thank you a lot!

That solved the issue.